# Prove that if $E \simeq E'$, $E \bigoplus F \simeq E' \bigoplus F'$ then $F \simeq F'$.

Tags: banach-spaces

All the spaces in this question are Banach Spaces, and "$\simeq$" means they are linear homeomorphic. The question is to prove the following:

Prove that if $E \simeq E'$, $E \bigoplus F \simeq E' \bigoplus F'$ then $F \simeq F'$.

Any hints on how to do this? I'm kind lost.

Thanks!

Comment: but the implication that $E \bigoplus F \simeq E \bigoplus F'$, how do i do it? I need to prove this!

Comment: This is not true.  Are you sure you have written the question correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's written correctly. the $\bigoplus$ is the direct sum of the two banach spaces. Why this isn't true?

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample: $\ell_2\oplus\Bbb R$ is linearly homeomorphic to $\ell_2\oplus\Bbb R^2$, but $\Bbb R$ is not linearly homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.